# Binomials to polynomial

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

What would be a nice way to conver the expression$$\binom{n}{2}+42\binom{n}{3} + 375\binom{n}{4} + 1450\binom{n}{5} + 2940\binom{n}{6} + 3360\binom{n}{7} + 1680\binom{n}{8}$$
to its corresponding $8-$degree polynomial in $n$?

I tried the manual one, but that is far from being beautiful and easy.
Any online tool?

Comment: Wolfram alpha?${}$

Comment: Can you show how?

Comment: How to use Wolfram alpha? Go to wolframalpha.com. There must be a help section there.

Comment: It is not about how to use it. I tried it there. It does not convert the binomial correctly.

Comment: [Over here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+C%28n%2C2%29+%2B+42C%28n%2C3%29+%2B+375+C%28n%2C4%29%2B+1450+C%28n%2C5%29+%2B+2940C%28n%2C6%29+%2B+3360C%28n%2C7%29+%2B+1680+C%28n%2C8%29) , the Taylor expansion at $0$ is probably correct (press the "More" button if you want the entire list of terms)? Probably is : the coefficient for $n^8$ matches for sure, now I see [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E8%2F24+-+n%5E7%2F2+%2B+%287+n%5E6%29%2F2+-+%2885+n%5E5%29%2F6+%2B+%28407+n%5E4%29%2F12+-+%28565+n%5E3%29%2F12+%2B+%28829+n%5E2%29%2F24+-+%2841+n%29%2F4), tables match.

Comment: Try expand(10(n choose 2)+35(n choose 5)) in Wolfram alpha.

Comment: You get $(7 n^5)/24 - (35 n^4)/12 + (245 n^3)/24 - (115 n^2)/12 + 2 n$. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. It has to be a polynomial in $n$ of degree 8.

Comment: It is $10 {n \choose 2} +35 {n \choose 5}$, has degree 5.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the link works.

Comment: It factors a little bit as $(1/24)n(n - 1)(n^6 - 11 n^5 + 73 n^4 - 267 n^3 + 547 n^2 - 583 n + 246)$, but that's as far as the nice factoring goes.

Comment: A Wolfram Alpha solution: Expand[FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, 2] + 42 Binomial[n, 3] + 375 Binomial[n, 4] +  1450 Binomial[n, 5] + 2940 Binomial[n, 6] + 3360 Binomial[n, 7] + 
 1680 Binomial[n, 8]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the identity $\,\binom{n}{k+1} = \frac{n-k}{k+1}\,\binom{n}{k}\,$ allows a rewrite reminiscent of  [Horner's scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method):

$$
\begin{align}
P(n) \;=\;\binom{n}{2}+42\binom{n}{3} + 375\binom{n}{4} + 1450\binom{n}{5} + 2940\binom{n}{6} + 3360\binom{n}{7} + 1680\binom{n}{8}
\\ = \binom{n}{2} \left(1 + \frac{n-2}{3}\left(42 + \frac{n-3}{4}\left(375+\frac{n-4}{5}\left(1450+
\\ +\frac{n-5}{6}\left(2940+\frac{n-6}{7}\left(3360+\frac{n-7}{8}\,1680\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Working from the innermost parenthesis outwards:

- $3360+\frac{n-7}{8}\,1680 = 210(n+9)$
- $2940+\frac{n-6}{7} \, 210(n+9) = 30 (n^2 + 3 n + 44)$
- $1450+\frac{n-5}{6} \, 30 (n^2 + 3 n + 44) = 5 (n^3 - 2 n^2 + 29 n + 70)$
- $375+\frac{n-4}{5} \, 5 (n^3 - 2 n^2 + 29 n + 70) = n^4 - 6 n^3 + 37 n^2 - 46 n + 95$
- $42 + \frac{n-3}{4} \, \left(n^4 - 6 n^3 + 37 n^2 - 46 n + 95\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left(n^5 - 9 n^4 + 55 n^3 - 157 n^2 + 233 n - 117\right)$
- $1 + \frac{n-2}{3} \, \frac{1}{4}\left(n^5 - 9 n^4 + 55 n^3 - 157 n^2 + 233 n - 117\right) = \frac{1}{12}\left(n^6 - 11 n^5 + 73 n^4 - 267 n^3 + 547 n^2 - 583 n + 246\right)$

The end result matches [Alexander](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/499816/alexander-burstein)'s previously posted [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327108/binomials-to-polynomial#comment9022040_4327108):

$$
P(n) \;=\; \frac{1}{24} n(n-1)\left(n^6 - 11 n^5 + 73 n^4 - 267 n^3 + 547 n^2 - 583 n + 246\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal to do the calculation in a manageable, not too cumbersome way. Given a polynomial

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=2}^8a_k\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> with $\color{blue}{(a_k)_{2\leq k\leq 8}=(1,42,375,1\,450,2\,940,3\,360,1\,680)}$ we are looking for a representation
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^8a_k\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{j=1}^8 b_j n^j}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> In (2) we start the right-hand sum with index $j=1$, since $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{k!}n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$ are polynomials which contain a factor $n$ and so the constant term is equal zero.

We recall binomial coefficients can be written using *[falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)*
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}
\end{align*}
and $n^{\underline{k}}$ admits a representation as polynomial in terms of $n^j$ using *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)*
\begin{align*}
n^{\underline{k}}=\sum_{j=1}^k\begin{bmatrix}k\\j\end{bmatrix}(-1)^{k-j}n^j\tag{3}
\end{align*}
The identity (3) can be found for instance as formula (6.13) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by Don Knuth et al.

> We can write the polynomial (1) using Stirling numbers of the first kind as
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=2}^8a_k\binom{n}{k}&=\sum_{k=2}^8\frac{a_k}{k!}n^{\underline{k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^8\frac{a_k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k\begin{bmatrix}k\\j\end{bmatrix}(-1)^{k-j}n^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^8\underbrace{\left(\color{blue}{
> \sum_{k=j}^{8}\begin{bmatrix}k\\j\end{bmatrix}(-1)^{k-j}\frac{a_k}{k!}}\right)}_{b_j}
> n^j\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We use the representation (4) to determine the coefficients $b_j, 1\leq j\leq 8$.

At first we observe that for each $b_j$ we need the factors $\frac{a_k}{k!}$. It is convenient to calculate them just once beforehand in a table. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
k&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\hline
\\
\frac{a_k}{k!}&\frac{1}{2!}&\frac{42}{3!}&\frac{375}{4!}&\frac{1\,450}{5!}&\frac{2\,940}{6!}&\frac{3\,360}{7!}&\frac{1\,680}{8!}\\
\\
\frac{a_k}{k!}&\frac{1}{2}&7&\frac{125}{8}&\frac{145}{12}&\frac{49}{12}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{24}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
In the last row we have $\frac{a_k}{k!}$ as reduced fraction.

Next we also list the Stirling number of the first kind we need.

The table $\begin{bmatrix}k\\j\end{bmatrix}, 1\leq j\leq k\leq 8$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrr}
k\backslash j&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&2&3&1\\
4&6&11&6&1\\
5&24&50&35&10&1\\
6&120&274&225&85&15&1\\
7&720&1\,764&1\,624&735&175&21&1\\
8&5\,040&13\,068&13\,132&6\,769&1\,960&322&28&1\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

Now we are well prepared to calculate the $b_j, 1\leq j\leq 8$.

> We do the easy parts first and calculate $b_j$ starting with $j=8$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b_8}&=\begin{bmatrix}8\\8\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{a_8}{8!}=1\cdot\frac{1}{24}\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{24}}\\
> \color{blue}{b_7}&=\begin{bmatrix}7\\7\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{a_7}{7!}-\begin{bmatrix}8\\7\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{a_8}{8!}
> =1\cdot\frac{2}{3}-28\cdot\frac{1}{24}\color{blue}{=-\frac{1}{2}}\\
> \color{blue}{b_6}&=\begin{bmatrix}6\\6\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{a_6}{6!}
> -\begin{bmatrix}7\\6\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{a_7}{7!}
> +\begin{bmatrix}8\\6\end{bmatrix}\,\frac{a_8}{8!}\\
> &=1\cdot\frac{49}{12}-21\cdot\frac{2}{3}+322\cdot\frac{1}{24}\color{blue}{=\frac{7}{2}}
> \end{align*}

We note it becomes somewhat more lengthy each step we perform. We can reduce the writing effort by using a more compact notation. We will use the dot-product notation $\langle (x_j)_{1\leq j\leq n},(y_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n x_jy_j$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b_5}&=\left\langle\left(\begin{bmatrix}5+j\\5\end{bmatrix}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 3},
> \left((-1)^j\frac{a_{5+j}}{(5+j)!}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 3}\right\rangle\\
> &=\left\langle\left(1,15,175,1\,960\right),\left(\frac{145}{12},-\frac{49}{12},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{24}\right)\right\rangle
> \,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{85}{6}}\\
> \color{blue}{b_4}&=\left\langle\left(\begin{bmatrix}4+j\\4\end{bmatrix}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 4},
> \left((-1)^j\frac{a_{4+j}}{(4+j)!}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 4}\right\rangle\\
> &=\left\langle\left(1,10,85,735,6\,769\right),\left(\frac{125}{8},-\frac{145}{12},\frac{49}{12},-\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{24}\right)\right\rangle
> \,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{407}{12}}\\
> \color{blue}{b_3}&=\left\langle\left(\begin{bmatrix}3+j\\3\end{bmatrix}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 5},
> \left((-1)^j\frac{a_{3+j}}{(3+j)!}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 5}\right\rangle\\
> &=\Bigg\langle\left(1,6,35,225,1\,624,13\,132\right),\\
> &\qquad\left(7,-\frac{125}{8},\frac{145}{12},-\frac{49}{12},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{24}\right)\Bigg\rangle
> \,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{565}{12}}\\
> \color{blue}{b_2}&=\left\langle\left(\begin{bmatrix}2+j\\2\end{bmatrix}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 6},
> \left((-1)^j\frac{a_{2+j}}{(2+j)!}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 6}\right\rangle\\
> &=\Bigg\langle\left(1,3,11,50,274,1\,764,13\,068\right),\\
> &\qquad\left(\frac{1}{2},-7,\frac{125}{8},-\frac{145}{12},\frac{49}{12},-\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{24}\right)\Bigg\rangle
> \,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{829}{24}}\\
> \color{blue}{b_1}&=\left\langle\left(\begin{bmatrix}1+j\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 7},
> \left((-1)^j\frac{a_{2+j}}{(2+j)!}\right)_{0\leq j\leq 7}\right\rangle\\
> &=\Bigg\langle\left(1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5\,040\right),\\
> &\qquad\left(0,-\frac{1}{2},7,-\frac{125}{8},\frac{145}{12},-\frac{49}{12},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{24}\right)\Bigg\rangle
> \,\,\color{blue}{=-\frac{41}{4}}\\
> \end{align*}

**Result:** Putting all together we can write the polynomial (1) as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^8 a_k\binom{8}{k}&
\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{24}n^8-\frac{1}{2}n^7+\frac{7}{2}n^6-\frac{85}{6}n^5+\frac{407}{12}n^4}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{-\frac{565}{12}n^3+\frac{829}{24}n^2-\frac{41}{4}n}
\end{align*}